# Get Year/Month/Day separately from MySQL datetime in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I store user register date and time as datetime in MySQL. now to do some process with that date i need to get year, month and day separately to work with.

for example:

2015-07-30 19:20:34

now I want 2015, how do I do that in PHP?

Comment: `date('y', strtotime('2015-07-30 19:20:34'));` I believe is what you're looking for

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones but date is limited to 2038

Comment: But the register dates for your users won't be 2038 for another 23 years.  That isn't a great reason to not use a current working solution - I'm sure newer versions of PHP (sometime in the next 2 decades...) will have a solution for this.

Answer (score 4):

```
date('Y', strtotime(<date string from mysql>));
```

The `strtotime` function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) parses your date string to a Unix timestamp, and then the `date` function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) outputs it in the defined format.

So you can do something like:

```
$date = '2015-07-30 19:20:34';
$year = date('Y', strtotime($date));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but try this:

```
<?php
$str="2015-07-30";
$explode=explode("-",$str);  
echo $explode[1];
?>
```

Comment: I actually want to to this then convert the date to Jalali calendar.

Comment: Do you want to convert the date??or you want to do anything else in addition?

Comment: just converting the date to Jalali.

Comment: JDF uses date which is limited to 2038.

Comment: I'm wasn't sure,so I Google it and found this,try it:`$fmt = new IntlDateFormatter("fa_IR@calendar=persian", IntlDateFormatter::FULL, IntlDateFormatter::FULL, 'Asia/Tehran', IntlDateFormatter::TRADITIONAL);`I think it changes the Timezone try to `echo` your date by:`$fmt->format(time())`

Answer (score 0):

```
$datetime = date_create("2015-07-30 19:20:34");

$day = date_format( $datetime, 'l'); // Thursday
$date = date_format( $datetime, 'd'); // 30
$month = date_format( $datetime, 'F'); // July
$year = date_format( $datetime, 'Y'); // 2015
```

[function.date php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) 
[datetime.format.php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple, you can use `strtotime()` function of PHP like this:

```
$dated=$row['timestamp'];// in this case '2015-07-30 19:20:34';
$FullYear=date('Y',strtotime($dated)); //  result 2015
$FullYear=date('y',strtotime($dated));  //  result 15
```

Answer (score -2):

```
date('Y', strtotime(<date string from mysql>));
$date = '2015-07-30 19:20:34';
$year = date('Y', strtotime($date));
```

It should work.

Comment: This is a direct copy/paste from my answer 3 years later...